# Error Opening Excel 2007 File

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, import-from-excel, comexception

I am not very familiar with the `OpenFileDialog` class, but am using it to select a file and open the file in a C# winform app.  This is my syntax, and when it hits the open line it has the correct filename, but it throws a debug error of `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server threw an exception` RPC Info: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)`and if memory serves, that is one of the most generic messages you can get.  Syntactically is this set-up properly?  Or how can I achieve my .xlsx file to be opened?

```
OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.Title = "Select The File To Open";
        fd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx";
        fd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Application xlsApp = new Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                Workbook wb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(fd.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("The file was opened");
            }
            catch (Exception grrr) { MessageBox.Show(grrr.ToString()); }
        }
```

Comment: I believe `COMException` normally gives an HRESULT error code that can help you decipher what has gone wrong.

Comment: Do you really *need* to interact with Excel? If you're just trying to import data from an Excel file, there's better ways to do that. Use a native library without external dependencies such as Open XML SDK, EPPlus, or NPOI (EPPlus is my choice). The're lighter weight, faster, have no dependencies, and at least the last two are easier to work with.

Comment: @mason - all I am needing to do is open the workbook, select the 1st column, ignore the 1st row, then read the remainder of the 1st column into an array.  Is this feasible using one of the native library's mentioned above?

Comment: @user2676140 Yes, of course.

Comment: @mason - interesting.  I will spend some time on google, looking up how to achieve such with EPPlus

Answer (score 1):

Check your references.  For example, if you have Excel 2000 set as default on the computer you are running this project on, but the reference is set for Excel 2007 (would show as Excel 12.0 object library) you will receive the above HRESULT error.

Quickest way to check IMO, is to look in your Solution Explorer and click the drop down arrow beside References and select the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and see what version is listed in the Description.